# backup distributed cache data to cloud storage

Tags: redis, google-cloud-storage, cloud, backup

I want to backup the REDIS data on google storage bucket as flat file, is there any existing utility to do that?
Although, I do not fully agree to idea of backing up of cache data on cloud. I was wondering if there is any existing utility rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Cloud Memorystore for Redis you can simply refer to the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/export-data#gcloud). Notice that you can simply use the following gcloud command:

`gcloud redis instances export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FILE_NAME].rdb [INSTANCE_ID] --region=[REGION] --project=[PROJECT_ID]`

or use the **Export** operation from the Cloud Console.

If you manage your own instance (e.g. you have the Redis instance hosted on a Compute Engine Instance) you could simply use the [SAVE](https://redis.io/commands/save) or [BGSAVE](https://redis.io/commands/bgsave) (preferred) commands to take a [snapshot of the instance](https://redis.io/topics/persistence#snapshotting) and then upload the .rdb file to Google Cloud Storage using any of the [available methods](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#gsutil), from which I think the most convenient one would be gsutil (notice that it will require the following [installation procedure](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#install)) in a similar fashion to:

`gsutil cp path/to/your-file.rdb gs://[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/`